# fontspec load font in Ubuntu Mantic

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

I am compiling with `xelatex sample.tex`, but am not able to use a font on the newer version of Ubuntu (Ubuntu Mantic). **How can I use the Ubuntu font in my compiled LaTeX PDF documents on Ubuntu Mantic without copying the fonts from an older Ubuntu distribution?**

Fonts have been changed from separate files (for example, Ubuntu Focal) to a single one (Ubuntu Mantic):

```
> # Ubuntu Mantic
> ls /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu
total 2.1M
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Sep 28 03:34  .
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root 4.0K Sep 28 03:34  ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   36 Aug 18 02:26  .uuid
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   21 Jun 21 08:35  Ubuntu-B.ttf -> 'Ubuntu[wdth,wght].ttf'
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   28 Jun 21 08:35  Ubuntu-BI.ttf -> 'Ubuntu-Italic[wdth,wght].ttf'
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   21 Jun 21 08:35  Ubuntu-C.ttf -> 'Ubuntu[wdth,wght].ttf'
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 664K Jun 21 08:34 'Ubuntu-Italic[wdth,wght].ttf'
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   21 Jun 21 08:35  Ubuntu-L.ttf -> 'Ubuntu[wdth,wght].ttf'
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   28 Jun 21 08:35  Ubuntu-LI.ttf -> 'Ubuntu-Italic[wdth,wght].ttf'
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   21 Jun 21 08:35  Ubuntu-M.ttf -> 'Ubuntu[wdth,wght].ttf'
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   28 Jun 21 08:35  Ubuntu-MI.ttf -> 'Ubuntu-Italic[wdth,wght].ttf'
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   21 Jun 21 08:35  Ubuntu-R.ttf -> 'Ubuntu[wdth,wght].ttf'
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   28 Jun 21 08:35  Ubuntu-RI.ttf -> 'Ubuntu-Italic[wdth,wght].ttf'
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   21 Jun 21 08:35  Ubuntu-Th.ttf -> 'Ubuntu[wdth,wght].ttf'
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   20 Jun 21 08:35  UbuntuMono-B.ttf -> 'UbuntuMono[wght].ttf'
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   27 Jun 21 08:35  UbuntuMono-BI.ttf -> 'UbuntuMono-Italic[wght].ttf'
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 169K Mar 24  2023 'UbuntuMono-Italic[wght].ttf'
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   20 Jun 21 08:35  UbuntuMono-R.ttf -> 'UbuntuMono[wght].ttf'
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   27 Jun 21 08:35  UbuntuMono-RI.ttf -> 'UbuntuMono-Italic[wght].ttf'
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 169K Mar 24  2023 'UbuntuMono[wght].ttf'
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1.1M Jun 21 08:34 'Ubuntu[wdth,wght].ttf'

> # Before Ubuntu Mantic
> ls /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu
total 4.3M
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Jul 31  2020 .
drwxr-xr-x 49 root root 4.0K Jul 31  2020 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 349K Jul 10  2015 Ubuntu-BI.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 326K Jul 10  2015 Ubuntu-B.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 343K Jul 10  2015 Ubuntu-C.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 401K Jul 10  2015 Ubuntu-LI.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 406K Jul 10  2015 Ubuntu-L.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 359K Jul 10  2015 Ubuntu-MI.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 212K Sep 26  2011 UbuntuMono-BI.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 187K Sep 26  2011 UbuntuMono-B.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 206K Sep 26  2011 UbuntuMono-RI.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 201K Sep 26  2011 UbuntuMono-R.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 334K Jul 10  2015 Ubuntu-M.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 378K Jul 10  2015 Ubuntu-RI.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 346K Jul 10  2015 Ubuntu-R.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 235K Mar  8  2019 Ubuntu-Th.ttf
```

I have installed [`fonts-ubuntu`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/mantic/all/fonts-ubuntu/filelist). It provides:

```
> fc-list Ubuntu
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/Ubuntu-Italic[wdth,wght].ttf: Ubuntu:style=Italic
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/Ubuntu[wdth,wght].ttf: Ubuntu:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/Ubuntu[wdth,wght].ttf: Ubuntu:style=Medium
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/Ubuntu[wdth,wght].ttf: Ubuntu:style=Condensed Thin
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/Ubuntu[wdth,wght].ttf: Ubuntu:style=Light
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/Ubuntu-Italic[wdth,wght].ttf: Ubuntu:style=Extra Bold Italic
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/Ubuntu-Italic[wdth,wght].ttf: Ubuntu:style=Condensed Bold Italic
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/Ubuntu[wdth,wght].ttf: Ubuntu:style=Condensed
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/Ubuntu[wdth,wght].ttf: Ubuntu:style=Condensed Medium
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/Ubuntu-Italic[wdth,wght].ttf: Ubuntu:style=Medium Italic
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/Ubuntu-Italic[wdth,wght].ttf: Ubuntu:style=Thin Italic
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/Ubuntu-Italic[wdth,wght].ttf: Ubuntu:style=Condensed Extra Bold Italic
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/Ubuntu[wdth,wght].ttf: Ubuntu:style=Extra Bold
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/Ubuntu[wdth,wght].ttf: Ubuntu:style=Condensed Extra Bold
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/Ubuntu-Italic[wdth,wght].ttf: Ubuntu:style=Condensed Medium Italic
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/Ubuntu[wdth,wght].ttf: Ubuntu
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/Ubuntu[wdth,wght].ttf: Ubuntu:style=Condensed Light
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/Ubuntu-Italic[wdth,wght].ttf: Ubuntu:style=Condensed Italic
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/Ubuntu-Italic[wdth,wght].ttf: Ubuntu:style=Light Italic
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/Ubuntu-Italic[wdth,wght].ttf: Ubuntu:style=Bold Italic
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/Ubuntu[wdth,wght].ttf: Ubuntu:style=Thin
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/Ubuntu-Italic[wdth,wght].ttf: Ubuntu:style=Condensed Thin Italic
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/Ubuntu-Italic[wdth,wght].ttf: Ubuntu
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/Ubuntu-Italic[wdth,wght].ttf: Ubuntu:style=Condensed Light Italic
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/Ubuntu[wdth,wght].ttf: Ubuntu:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/Ubuntu[wdth,wght].ttf: Ubuntu:style=Condensed Bold
```

---

```
\setmainfont[Path=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu]{Ubuntu-L.ttf}
```

gives the error

```
! Package fontspec Error: The font "Ubuntu-L" cannot be found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...
```

---

`\setmainfont{Ubuntu:style=Light}` and `\setmainfont{"Ubuntu:style=Light"}` (with quotes around name) gives `xdvipdfmx:fatal: Invalid font: -1 (0)`

---

Before Ubuntu Mantic, this works:

```
\setmainfont{Ubuntu Light}[ItalicFont=Ubuntu Light Italic]
```

On Ubuntu Mantic, it says

```
! Package fontspec Error: The font "Ubuntu Light" cannot be found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...
```

---

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

% Works on Ubuntu distributions before Mantic Minotaur
\setmainfont{Ubuntu Light}[ItalicFont=Ubuntu Light Italic]

\begin{document}
Hello, World!
\end{document}
```

**Important**: this works on Ubuntu distributions before Mantic Minotaur, but not on Mantic Minotaur.

Comment: XeTeX on Ubuntu needs a bit of extra setup for `fc-cache` to cache the TeX font files. [This might do it.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/553305/61644)